# Inner Join Sqlite com Cursor no Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, cursor, inner-join

Bom dia pessoal, poderiam me tirar um dúvida ? Como devo fazer um `Inner Join` no `SQLite` utilizando o `Cursor` ? Abaixo está o meu código, porém não sei como encaixa-lo na linha.

```
final SQLiteDatabase d5 = dadosOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
final Cursor cursor5 = d5.query("produto" , new String[]{"produto.descricao", "produto.ean", "produto.status", "produto.precoprod", "categoria.descricao", "produto.cod"}, null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em situações como essa use o método [public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, 
                String[] selectionArgs)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) da classe SQLiteDatabase.

O método retorna um Cursor com o resultado da *query* passada ao primeiro parâmetro.

Comment: Obrigado, eu li a documentação e consegui fazer o Inner Join, irei postar o resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Código arrumado e funcionando:

```
final SQLiteDatabase d5 = dadosOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String rawQuery = "SELECT produto.descricao, produto.ean, produto.status, produto.precoprod, categoria.descricao, produto.cod FROM produto  INNER JOIN categoria  ON categoria.id  = produto.codigocateg";
        Cursor cursor5 = d5.rawQuery(
                rawQuery,
                null
        );
```